# Can this function be optimized for speed?

Tags: python, performance, list, optimization

I am writing a long piece of code, which is taking way too long to execute. I used  [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) on the code, I found that the following function is called 150 times and takes 1.3 seconds per call, leading to around 200 seconds to this function alone. The function is -

```
def makeGsList(sentences,org):
    gs_list1=[]
    gs_list2=[]
    for s in sentences:
        if s.startswith(tuple(StartWords)):
            s = s.lower()
            if org=='m':
                gs_list1 = [k for k in m_words if k in s]
            if org=='h':
                gs_list1 = [k for k in h_words if k in s]
            for gs_element in gs_list1:
                gs_list2.append(gs_element)
    gs_list3 = list(set(gs_list2))
    return gs_list3
```

The code is supposed to take a list of sentences and a flag `org`. Then it goes through each line, checks if it starts with any of the words present in the list `StartWords`, and then lower-cases it. Then, depending on the value of `org`, it makes a list of all words in the current sentence which are also present in either `m_words` or `h_words`. It keeps appending these words to another list `gs_list2`. Finally it makes a set of `gs_list2` and returns it.

Can someone give me any suggestion as to how I can optimize this function to reduce the time taken to execute?

**NOTE** - The words `h_words`/`m_words` are not all single words, many of them are phrases containing 3-4 words within them.

**Some examples -**

```
StartWords = ['!Series_title','!Series_summary','!Series_overall_design','!Sample_title','!Sample_source_name_ch1','!Sample_characteristics_ch1']

sentences = [u'!Series_title\t"Transcript profiles of DCs of PLOSL patients show abnormalities in pathways of actin bundling and immune response"\n', u'!Series_summary\t"This study was aimed to identify pathways associated with loss-of-function of the DAP12/TREM2 receptor complex and thus gain insight into pathogenesis of PLOSL (polycystic lipomembranous osteodysplasia with sclerosing leukoencephalopathy). Transcript profiles of PLOSL patients\' DCs showed differential expression of genes involved in actin bundling and immune response, but also for the stability of myelin and bone remodeling."\n', u'!Series_summary\t"Keywords: PLOSL patient samples vs. control samples"\n', u'!Series_overall_design\t"Transcript profiles of in vitro differentiated DCs of three controls and five PLOSL patients were analyzed."\n', u'!Series_type\t"Expression profiling by array"\n', u'!Sample_title\t"potilas_DC_A"\t"potilas_DC_B"\t"potilas_DC_C"\t"kontrolli_DC_A"\t"kontrolli_DC_C"\t"kontrolli_DC_D"\t"potilas_DC_E"\t"potilas_DC_D"\n',  u'!Sample_characteristics_ch1\t"in vitro differentiated DCs"\t"in vitro differentiated DCs"\t"in vitro differentiated DCs"\t"in vitro differentiated DCs"\t"in vitro differentiated DCs"\t"in vitro differentiated DCs"\t"in vitro differentiated DCs"\t"in vitro differentiated DCs"\n', u'!Sample_description\t"DAP12mut"\t"DAP12mut"\t"DAP12mut"\t"control"\t"control"\t"control"\t"TREM2mut"\t"TREM2mut"\n']

h_words = ['pp1665', 'glycerophosphodiester phosphodiesterase domain containing 5', 'gde2', 'PLOSL patients', 'actin bundling', 'glycerophosphodiester phosphodiesterase 2', 'glycerophosphodiester phosphodiesterase domain-containing protein 5']
```

m_words are similar.

**Regarding sizes -**

The length of both lists `h_words` and `m_words` is **around 250,000**. And each element in the lists is on an average 2 words long. The list of sentences is around 10-20 sentences long and I have provided an example list to give you the idea of how big each sentence can be.

Comment: should go to code review stackexchange if your code is working fine

Comment: 1. Think about what's in `gs_list1` after every iteration. 2. Why not *start* with a set?

Comment: Can you guarantee that `org` will _always_ be either 'm' or 'h'?

Comment: @PM2Ring, yes, only these two

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use global variables for `m_words` and `k_words`.
2. Put the `if` statements outside of the `for` loop.
3. Cast `tuple(StartWords)` once and for all.
4. Use a programatically created regex instead of list comprehension.
5. Pre-compile everything you can.
6. Directly extend your list instead of iterating trough it to `append()` each element.
7. Use a `set` from the start instead of a `list`.
8. Use set comprehension instead of explicit `for` loop.

---

```
m_reg = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(w) for w in m_words))
h_reg = re.compile("|".join(re.escape(w) for w in h_words))

def make_gs_list(sentences, start_words, m_reg, h_reg, org):
    if org == 'm':
        reg = m_reg
    elif org == 'h':
        reg = h_reg

    matched = {w for s in sentences if s.startswith(start_words)
                 for w in reg.findall(s.lower())}

    return matched
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. As mentioned in my edit, since the lists `m_words` and `h_words` are both huge (250,000 entries in each), would it be better to do the compile (for both) just once in the main function, and pass `reg_m` and `reg_h` to this function? 

Also, why do you think that passing `start_words`, `m_words`, `h_words` as function arguments is faster than using global variables for them?

Comment: @user1993 If you are able to pre-compile the regex, yes you should do so! Local variables are usually faster than global ones.

Comment: @user1993 Also, let me know how musch faster it is compared to your first function, I am curious.

Comment: @user1993 I am curious about using regex instead of `startswith` too, as suggested by Gribouillis. The `*` is necessary to unpack the element in the matched words, otherwise it will construct the set using lists.

Comment: i tried this, but it's giving the error - `sre_constants.error: bad character range l-c at position 194661` at `re.compile`. Difficult to check what's causing it

Comment: Also, with the `*`, it gives the error - `SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension`

Comment: @user1993 The regex error is because of unicode, I guess. The syntax error is because you are using Python 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149290/discussion-between-user1993-and-delgan).

Answer (score 1):

I would try this

```
# optionaly change these regexes
FIRST_WORD_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z]+")
LOWER_WORD_RE = re.compile(r"[a-z]+")
m_or_h_words = {'m': set(m_words), 'h': set(h_words)}
startwords_set = set(StartWords)

def makeGsList(sentences, org):
    words = m_or_h_words[org]
    gs_set2 = set()
    for s in sentences:
        mo = FIRST_WORD_RE.match(s)
        if mo and mo.group(0) in startwords_set:
            gs_set2 |= set(LOWER_WORD_RE.findall(s.lower())) & words
    return list(gs_set2)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have a couple of questions - 1. why do you think using regexes is better than `.startswith`? 2. what does `|=` do?

Comment: I don't know exactly the `.startswith()` algorithm. I suspect it traverses all the words, which can be inefficient if there are many words. Also, I know from programming languages parsing techniques that the most efficient way to recognize keywords in a text is to have a word regex and use lookup in a set or dictionary. You can use timeit to compare the two approaches. The `|=` performs set union, in an incremental way (`|` is the binary union operator for the set type).

Comment: I think there is an error in the line - `gs_set2 |= set(LOWER_WORD_RE.findall(s.lower()) & words` because my compiler gives an error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for any line I put after that

Comment: All right, it is `gs_set2 |= set(LOWER_WORD_RE.findall(s.lower())) & words`. There was a missing parenthesis

Comment: I tried your method with the addtion that I added space and hyphen too in the LOWER_WORD_RE, to make it - `LOWER_WORD_RE = re.compile(r"[a-z0-9 /-]+")`. Now, it is able to also include multi- words entites in the `h_words`. The only problem though is that this regex is extremely greedy, hence the matches it finds (using `LOWER_WORD_RE.findall(s.lower())`) end only when there is a character which is not part of `[a-z0-9 /-]`. As a result many times the match it finds contains a lot more than the entity present in `h_words` and hence the `&` function does not give the right result. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's difficult to try anything significant without a more realistic set of data similar to the one you profiled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take your first crack at this by tokenizing your sentences

so you'd do:

## Use a regex here instead of split, but just for illustration use split

sentences = tuple(s.split(' ') for s in sentences)
then instead of using startswith, take your StartsWords and put them in a set

so
sw_set = {w for w in StartsWords}

then as you iterate your sentences, do:
if s[0] in sw_set:
   # proceed to the rest of your logic

I think that's where you're taking the biggest performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, searching a set is much faster than searching a list, so you can always convert a your list to set then try to search word(s) on set instead of list. Here is my sample code:

```
 for i in range(0, num_reviews):
    text = raw_review["review"][i]).lower()  # Convert to lower case
    words = text.split()  # Split into words
    ### convert the stopwords from list to a set
    stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    # Remove stop words from "words"
    meaningful_words = [w for w in words if not w in stops]
    # Join the words back into one string
    BS_reviews.append(" ".join(meaningful_words))
 return BS_reviews
```